# How to execute a method after every 12 hours inside console application

Tags: c#, timer

The requirement is to call a method after every 12 hours. The code below the method call should keep on running in different thread, how can we achieve this?

```
void ExecuteAfterTimeInterval()
{
  //some code
}

public static void main(string[] args)
{
  //call the below method after every 12 hours
  ExecuteAfterTimeInterval();


// run the below code in separate thread
  // some code here 
  //some code here
  //some code here

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the scheduler to launch the app every 12 hours?

Comment: Agreed with @BrianRasmussen. A timer in a console app is a very unreliable approach. What if someone closes the console window, or the application crashes? What if the computer restarts? If you insist on doing this, just look up any of the `Timer` classes in the .NET framework.

Comment: They were not looking for a task to be run every 12 hours there are 2 tasks involved that need to run together 1 runs every 12 hours the other is consistently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. Look for //SET BREAK POINT HERE and run.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program console = new Program();
            console.MyMethodAsync();
        }

        void ExecuteAfterTimeInterval()
        {
            //some code
        }

        public async Task MyMethodAsync()
        {
            Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperationAsync();

            // run the below code in separate thread
            //some code here 
            //some code here
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i); //SET BREAK POINT HERE
            }
            //some code here

            //and now we call await on the task 
            int result = await longRunningTask;
        }

        public async Task<int> LongRunningOperationAsync() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
        {

            bool retry = true;

            using (AutoResetEvent wait = new AutoResetEvent(false))
            {
                while (retry)
                {

                    //Do Work here
                    //await Task.Delay(43200000); //12 hour delay
                    await Task.Delay(3000); //SET BREAK POINT HERE
                }
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```